# Comparing values of type Integer with values of type Text

Tags: text, filter, count, format, dax

Could someone please explain to me why I'm getting this error:

> DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type
> Integer with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT
> function to convert one of the values.

I'm trying to count a text value if it meets the condition stated in below script. The values I'm comparing both are of the same format(whole number). The condition is based on 2 different tables.

```
    IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTA ( 'tbl1'[type] ),
        FILTER ( 'tbl1', 'tbl1'[Memno] = 'tbl2'[mempersonid] )
    ) = "",
    "No engagement",
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTA ( 'tbl1'[type] ),
        FILTER ( 'tbl1', 'tbl1'[Memno] = 'tbl2'[mempersonid] )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certain that of the two columns being compared ( `'tbl1'[Memno]` and `'tbl2'[mempersonid]` ), one is an *Integer* and one is *Text*.

They may LOOK the same, but check the actual data types.

Answer (score 0):

If `[Memno]` and `[mempersondid]` are indeed both whole numbers, then the issue is with

```
CALCULATE ( COUNTA ( ... ), ... ) = ""
```

CALCULATE returns a number and you are trying to compare with the empty string `""`.

Try this instead:

```
VAR TypeCount =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTA ( 'tbl1'[type] ),
        FILTER ( 'tbl1', 'tbl1'[Memno] = 'tbl2'[mempersonid] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( TypeCount ), "No engagement", TypeCount )
```